# How to change "remote process types" for Heroku deploy with Docker

Tags: python, heroku, docker, docker-compose

I am deploying a `docker` container to `Heroku` and deploying the incorrect `remote process types`. I am not sure why this is happening...

My `Procfile` is:

```
web: python app.py
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python app.py
  working_dir: /app
  environment:
    PORT: 8080
  ports:
    - '8080:5000'
shell:
  build: .
  command: bash
  working_dir: /app
  environment:
    PORT: 8080
  ports:
    - '8080:5000'
  volumes:
    - '.:/app'
```

For some reason when I deploy using `heroku docker:release` I get:

```
Remote addons:  (0)                                                                  Local addons:  (0)                                                                Missing addons:  (0)                                                                      Creating local slug...                                                              Building web                                                                          Step 1 : FROM t206cv:latest                                                              ---> af69b4ac9de8
Successfully built af69b4ac9de8
extracting slug from container...
creating remote slug...
language-pack: heroku-docker (t206cv:latest)
remote process types: { web: 'cd /app/user && python app.py' }
uploading slug [====================] 100% of 127 MB, 0.0s
releasing slug...
Successfully released still-depths-21391!
```

How can I change

```
remote process types: { web: 'cd /app/user && python app.py' }
```

to

```
remote process types: { web: 'cd /app && python app.py' }
```

Comment: Is this `/app/user` directory left over from a previous build you did?  If you rebuild with  `docker-compose build`, does that fix it?

Comment: That didn't work...one thing I left out, when I ran `heroku docker:init` and the `docker-compose.yml` file was auto-generated, it contained `/app/user` as the path. Not sure why. I had to change them manually to what I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/docker#initialize-docker-assets-for-the-app) seem to indicate that both the `docker-compose.yml`, and `Dockerfile` are generated from an `app.json` file, when you run: `heroku docker:init`.

The `/app/user` path is likely in there, and would probably be the best place to change (and then just run `heroku docker:init` again).

Alternatively, this path may be in the `Dockerfile`, and just changing it there (as well as your .yml file) may fix your issue.

**EDIT:**

It looks like the `app/user` directory is hard-coded in [heroku-docker](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-docker/blob/master/lib/directory.js), itself, in `directory.js`.  Seems odd, but that may be the only place you can change it.

...and also appears to be hard-coded in [docker.js](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-docker/blob/master/lib/docker.js), which seems to be the source of the docker-compose.yml file generated.

Comment: That didn't work. When i ran `heroku docker:init` again, it overwrote the `docker-compose.yml` file and I had to change the `app/user` path again.

Comment: Was this `/app/user` path in an `app.json` file, and did you change it there?   ...and did you look in the `Dockerfile` to see if it was in there as well?

Comment: No it was not. I'm not sure why it appends this `/user` to the `/app` path, but I see the `app/user` path in a lot of other posts that reference `heroku docker:release` commands, such as: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/issues/190

Comment: @jdesilvio:  ...did you change `WORKDIR` in the generated `Dockerfile`?

Comment: initially I didn't, but I play around with resetting the `WORKDIR` and it didn't make a difference. It still put `cd app/user` in the command.